# Unable to debug Xamarin application via USB debugging

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms

This is the error

```
> am start -a "android.intent.action.MAIN" -c "android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" -n "PictureApp.jiahong/crc64ad68f59cd763e462.PictureApp"
> Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=PictureApp.jiahong/crc64ad68f59cd763e462.PictureApp }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {PictureApp.jiahong/crc64ad68f59cd763e462.PictureApp} does not exist.
Failed to launch android application
```

Not sure what's wrong with it. I've tried everything on all the SO answers, and it still doesn't work.
AndroidManifest.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="PictureApp.jiahong" android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="22" android:targetSdkVersion="29" />
    <application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" android:label="App1" android:theme="@style/MainTheme" android:icon="@mipmap/icon">
        <provider android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider" android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
        </provider>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MEDIA_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.LOCATION_HARDWARE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" android:required="true" />
</manifest>
```

I've changed most things where I can to PictureApp instead of App1 but still nothing. I don't know what else I can provide. So if I'm missing something comment it and I'll add it. I am completely lost and I have no idea what to do.

Comment: You means that you can not run app on android device? Double-click **Android properties**, under the **Android Options page**,Click the **Advanced** button and, under **Supported architectures**, select all supported ABIs.

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT All ABIs under **Supported architectures** have already been selected, but the error still persists.

Comment: can you try to debug your project at android emulator?

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT Debugging on an emulator works fine. But I need to work with a bluetooth device, and I can't do that unless the debugging works on a physical android device.

Comment: You can try to use another device to test again, let see whether there is also having problem.

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT I managed to fix it, apparently something to do with private spaces. If interested I can link the github issue I opened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had about 20 instances of the same app installed in the PrivateSpace of my same device. Had to delete all instances for it to properly work. As suggested in this Github [comment](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/5759#issuecomment-806597003).

Comment: Can you tell me how you deleted it? İ need some help.

Comment: I just deleted it like normal. Check if you have a PrivateSpace setup on your device.

Comment: I had the same error. I noticed that the exported package type is set to `Bundle`. Changing it with `apk` solved the problem.